# Do I need to study Group Representations before learning Rings in Artin's Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, advice

I studied the first 9 chapters of Artin's *Algebra*, and we will start from chapter 11, Rings, in next semester. Do I need to preview Group Representations, chapter 10, before studying Rings, chapter 11?

Comment: For rings we need only very few prerequisites, e.g., abelian groups, polynomials, matrices and so on. In general, I would study what's coming up and review something in addition (wikipedia) if really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: rings and modules may be studied for quite a while without a background in group representations and, if I recall correctly, this should be the case for Artin's *Algebra*, which covers more or less the topics for an undergraduate course in commutative algebra.